# Setting up PXE boot server for Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: networking, boot, ubuntu-11.04, optical-media

I want to setup a pxe boot server for installing linux 11.04 amd64 server edition on some blade servers. I had installed 10.04 last year and it worked nicely. I am following same procedure for 11.04 but it is looking for an installation disk in CD-ROM at 3rd step (after keyboard and language options). I tried exporting linux iso cd using nfs mount but on the client side it is unable to mount and when i try to mount it by using shell (available while installation) it shows network unreachable or no network connectivity. If it is not connected to network then how can it pick up linux kernel image and initrd.gz file from tftp server.

I am almost totally confused. Even a little clarification will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide any information on how you did it and what you did the installation before.

But did you try to PXE the ISO from here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

Or why don't you just use the (extracted) netboot.tar.gz from the same location? As it is documented at https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/amd64/howto-getting-images.html.

Comment: I agree with you that i have not provided enough information but your links gave direction to me. I was assuming that initrd.gz as well as vmlinuz are same for both netboot and cdboot. I was using the one which is used for cd and so it was seeking for cd inbetween. netboot folder contains all the required contents and it booted as expected in the very first go. Thanks again